# mapGetters from not an index.js store file

Tags: vue.js, store, vuex, nuxt.js

I want to map getters from `store/app.js` file for example. I have a `sidebar()` getter in this file. In my component file I call:

```
export default {

  // ...

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      sidebar: 'app/sidebar'
    }),

    // ...

    isCollapse() {
      return !this.sidebar.opened
    }
  }
}
```

but looks like it doesn't work, I received `TypeError: Cannot read property 'opened' of undefined`

`store/app.js`:

```
// ...

export const state = () => ({
  sidebar: {
    opened: true
  }
})

export const mutations = {
  // ...
}

export const actions = {
  // ...
}

export const getters = {
  sidebar(state) {
    return state.sidebar
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your store setup? Do you use modules? Namespaced or not?

Comment: I have added `store/app.js` file to the my nuxt project, I have updated my question with content of that file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with nuxt, so this is just a thought.

I don't see anything wrong with your setup. A cursory look at https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store implies that maybe a `store/index.js` file is required which you didn't mention.

If that doesn't work, I suggest adding this to your component to help debugging:

```
created() {
  console.log(this.$store); // <-- this is the vuex store accessed by the component
}
```